# Issue with showing/hiding JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with showing and hiding two divs. I have two links: "Write Post" and "Send Message." For some reason, to get either div to appear I have to click the link twice. I thought it might be that I was attempting to click it before the page had been loaded, but that did not fix the issue. On page load, the divs are set to `display:none` and then I use JS to modify the style property. You can view the issue [here](http://www.mattaltepeter.com/purduepals/show_user.php)

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" />
    function showPost(id) {
if(document.getElementById('post').style.display == 'block' && id == 'send') {
    document.getElementById('post').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
else if(document.getElementById('send').style.display == 'block' && id == 'post') {
    document.getElementById('send').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
else if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using inline styles (`style="display: block;"`) to style the element initially? Because that's where `node.style.display` will be looking to test your `if` condition.

Comment: No, I am using CSS. Would it only check that on the first run? Because as soon as I click it twice it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why it would work after the second click. Can you post a demo, to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) or similar, to show us what's happening in an environment in which we can manipulate and correct the code?

Comment: Your code sets the style attribute to `display: none` on first click, which is why you need to click twice for it to show. That is caused by your display being set in the CSS only initially and not inline on the elements themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `post` and `send` elements don't seem to have the style attribute on load. It doesn't help to have the `display:none` in the css only, it needs to be applied to the element itself.

Adding `style="display:none;"` to both elements will solve your problem.

```
<div id="post" style="display: none;">
<div id="send" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using CSS, I don't think that the element.style.display is finding the style associated with the element. Therefore, I believe that on the first click, your function defaults to the else condition, thereby setting the display style of the element clicked to 'none'. This means that on the second click, one of the first conditions will be met and your function would then work correctly. Try using your styles inline :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove "display: none" from style.css

```
#post, #send {
width: 166.5%;
height: 195px;
border: 3px solid #DDD;
background: #E7EBF2;
margin-left: -67%;
margin-top: -107px;
/*display: none;*/
}
```

And in your HTML add  `style="display:none"` for div's (post and send)

`<div id="post">` to `<div id="post" style="display:none">`

`<div id="send">` to `<div id="send" style="display:none">`

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('post').style.display / document.getElementById('send').style.display returning empty string, hence else condition is executed for the first time.